# Is ocaml compiler use compiler front-end module parse to parse the source code or use ocamlyacc to parse source code?

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml

I try to read ocaml compiler source code,use 4.07 source code

I read it from driver/main.ml

I notice it use driver/pparse.ml line 161 function "parse" to parse lex buf
(I add a line Printf.printf "pparse.parse" and after make world,I use boot/ocamlrun ./ocamlc -nostdlib -I stdlib -c a.ml to test it,the console write "pparse.parse"):

```
let parse (type a) (kind : a ast_kind) lexbuf: a =
match kind with
| Structure->Parse.implementation lexbuf
| Signature->Parse.interface lexbuf
```

I want to know the Parse.implementation is the function implementation is from the compiler front-end lib here:
https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/parsing.html

or

from parseing/parse.ml,line 61:

```
let implementation = wrap Parser.implementation
```

and after "make world",the ocamlyacc generate parser.ml at floder parse 
after "make world",the function Parser.implementation is:

```
let implementation (lexfun:Lexing.lexbuf -> token) (lexbuf : Lexing.lexbuf) = 
(Parsing.yyparse yytables 1 lexfun lexbuf : Parsetree.structure)
```

I do not know which the ocaml compiler really use.

I change the function parse like this:

```
let parse (type a) (kind : a ast_kind) lexbuf : a =
match kind with
| Structure -> 
Printf.printf "pparse.parse";
let a=Parse.implementation lexbuf in
let writehandle = open_out "/home/wk/prog/LocationTest/parsed" in
let fmt = Format.formatter_of_out_channel writehandle in
Format.fprintf fmt "%a@." Pprintast.structure a ;
close_out writehandle;
```

and after "make world",it works fine.but after boot/ocamlrun ./ocamlc -nostdlib -I stdlib -c a.ml,the file parsed is the same as a.ml,even the a.ml is a complicated program

is it too complicated?can you help me?thanks

and is there a book or other doc,that can teach me the ocaml's compiler?thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser itself is generated by ocamlyacc (or menhir in OCaml 4.08) as `parsing/parser.ml` from `parsing/parser.mly`. The module `parsing/parse` wraps the resulting function to add some parser error handling. Finally, the module `driver/pparse` is another layer on top of `parsing/parse` that handles setting up the parser environment and preprocessing phases.

The compiler-libs library then reexport some of the internal modules of the compilers.

See https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/parsing/HACKING.adoc for some supplementary information.

Comment: Thanks,so the "Parse.implementation"  in line "| Structure->Parse.implementation lexbuf" is not from the  https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/parsing.html ?but how to know it?

Comment: Like I said, compiler-libs bundles some internal modules of the compiler. Thus https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Parse.html is exactly the same module as `parsing/parse`, but the compiler itself does not use compiler-libs.